# Jenkins proxy 407 error

Tags: java, apache, jenkins, proxy, ntlm

I'm running **Jenkins CI** inside a corporate network which uses a proxy for internet access.

I tried to configure proxy details in *Plugins->Advanced*, but even though the credentials are correct (yeah, I checked it a bunch of times), it cannot validate "Test URL" even on http://google.com and returns

> Failed to connect to http://google.com (code 407).

Strangely, Jenkins is still able to download plugins itself (whoa!), but totally unable to connect to any HTTP resource. The message that outputs from the console is:

> ←[0mApr 16, 2015 1:58:56 PM
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector pro
>   cessProxyAuthChallenge INFO: Failure authenticating with NTLM @proxyrye.asg.com:80 Apr 16, 2015 2:09:09 PM
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector execute WithRetry
>   INFO: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing
>   request: Connection timed out: connect Apr 16, 2015 2:09:09 PM
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector execute WithRetry
>   INFO: Retrying request Apr 16, 2015 2:09:10 PM
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthChallengeProcesso r
>   selectAuthScheme INFO: ntlm authentication scheme selected ←[31mApr
>   16, 2015 2:09:10 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector
>   au thenticate SEVERE: Credentials cannot be used for NTLM
>   authentication: org.apache.commons.h
>   ttpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.InvalidCredentialsException:
>   Credentials cann ot be used for NTLM authentication:
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswo rdCredentials
>           at org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.NTLMScheme.authenticate(NTLMScheme
>   .java:332)

Answer (score 8):

We had this issue a rather long time with our Jenkins behind our company's proxy. The other day they changed the order of authentication schemes our proxy desires. This was the day our Jenkins stopped connecting to the internet.

Obviously [Jenkins is not able to connect via a proxy that requires NTML authentication](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-3350). This was what lead me [to issue an improvement for Jenkins to extend the proxy configuration screen](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32293). During the work on the extension I discovered that Jenkins does not make use of all proxy related system properties, therefore it cannot work with NTLM.

As such the answer for a proxy that allows *only* NTLM authentication is: it will not work via the Jenkins UI.

**But** if your proxy allows other authentication schemes, you can follow our workaround, it is rather simple: add the java system property `-Dhttp.auth.preference="basic"` to your Jenkins startup script or to that one of your container.

This will force the underlying libraries and Java mechanisms Jenkins makes use of to connect to your proxy using basic authentication, not NTLM.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

for Java JDK8 and above, Oracle has disabled basic auth tunnelling for Basic authentication. If you want to use Basic mode again (security will be compromised), execute Jenkins adding this parameter to your JAVA_OPTS variable

```
    "-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="
```

default value is

```
    "-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=Basic",
```

as Basic scheme is DISABLED by default, it will return HTTP 407 error even if your credentials were OK.

more on link https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-48775 Thanks to Israel Romero Fiji

Answer (score 1):

The below solution worked for me for the 407 problem in Windows 7 machine.

- 1. Stop Jenkins from Windows Services
- 2. Goto Services.msc > Jenkins > Right Click > Properties > Logon > This account and type in your username and password
- 3. Click Apply and Ok
- 3. Start Jenkins

Comment: Great! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error while running jenkins with jetty server on jdk 8.

To resolve issue follow below steps:

**Step 1:**

Open URL https://updates.jenkins.io/ in browser

**Step 2:**

To export the Intermediate certificate:

Internet Explorer -> Tools -> Internet Options -> Content -> Certificates ->
Go to Trusted Root Certification Authorities Tab and find out the DST Root CA X3 certificate. Then Export the Certificate:
Select Certificate -> Export -> DER encoded Binary Format -> Save
save the certificate as jenkins.cer (for me it was saved to C:\jenkins\jenkins.cer

( From Firefox -> Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Encryption -> View Certificates )

**Step 3:** 
create keystore with name cacertskeystore

JAVA_HOME\bin\keytool -keystore C:\jenkins\cacertskeystore -genkey -alias cacerts

**Step 4:**

Add jenkins.cer to cacertskeystore using below command

JAVA_HOME\bin\keytool -import -trustcacerts -Keystore C:\jenkins\cacertskeystore -alias jenkins -file C:\jenkins\jenkins.cer

Step 5: Start jetty server with below command
JAVA_HOME\bin\java -DJENKINS_HOME=C:/jenkins/home -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:/jenkins/cacertskeystore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password-provided-while-creating-keystore -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8080--httpListenAddress=localhost

Answer (score 1):

I found this question while affected by bug: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-48775

The temporary workaround is to open the Jenkins script console and type
`ProxyConfiguration.open(new java.net.URL("http://jenkins.io")).content`

Since it's an http url, and not an https url, it will refresh some caches and make the plugin manager work with the proxy settings, at least for some time. See the bug report for more details.

Comment: This works, but when Jenkins restarts (and in some other cases) it needs to be redone. Therefore I do support this as a workaround, but not as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you parse the exception, it states

> Credentials cannot be used for NTLM authentication

So according to https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/jenkins-the-definitive/9781449311155/ch04s09.html you might need to provide a domain name as well.

> If your proxy is using Microsoft’s NTLM authentication scheme, then you will need to provide a domain name as well as a username. You can place both in the User name field: just enter the domain name, followed by a back-slash (\), followed by the username, such as “MyDomain\Joe Bloggs”.

Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not that easy. I have tried both to provide and not provide domain name before a username - still to no avail.

Comment: I also was not able to authenticate with my domain\user.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today, and it finally ended up being a space at the end of the Spira URI in the Spira configuration. Must've been a bad copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

I got the Failed to connect to http://google.com (code 407) error in Test. But jenkins can check new version and install plugins&updates.

Put in credentials regardless of the Test. Then Save and go to available plugins/check jenkins version to check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Hack:**
Try using the IP of the domain rather than the address. `-Dhttp.auth.preference="basic"` actually didn't work for me :(

PS. Change both the browser and proxy and the Jenkins proxy to the IP

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced same issue of **jenkins-proxy-407-error**

I have found work around for that, I Hope it will be useful for other users :

You can install **Cntlm Authentication Proxy** , it stands between your applications and the corporate proxy, adding NTLM authentication on-the-fly.

See here http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/

Once you install CNTLM, add your NTLM credentials in a file **cntlm.ini** . You can also configure Listen port or default to 3128 .

Find detailed instruction of CNTLM installation here

https://vijiboy.wordpress.com/2018/03/14/configure-cntlm-to-generate-hash-for-your-password-h-and-verify-m/

Start CNTLM service and go to jenkins, add

**host:** host name or localhost

**port:** Listen port specified in cntlm.ini or default 3128

keep username and password blank and you are set to use Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is so simple
If you tried to edit
jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=Basic
to
jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=
at location C:.......\java-1.8.0-openjdk\jre\lib\net.properties

Then later try to enter
fill this section with proper entries
Done.
[Check this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2CfC.png)