# Jenkins: IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required"

Tags: java, jenkins, proxy

First of all I want to tell that this question isn´t **duplicate**.

I want to install plugin in Jenkins. I went to Update Center but I can´t install anything because I have this error:

```
IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required".
```

[image: Here is how my error looks like in Update Center.]

Also when it comes to Java, I have Java for 64 bit.

I tried changing JRE folder and putting there things for JRE 64 bit because Jenkins installs 32bit but it doesn't work. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe this will help https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JenkinsBehindProxy

Comment: Not really, I have proxy that I should use and it should work but problem is in something else...

Comment: Also, some [discussion here: Jenkins proxy 407 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682844/jenkins-proxy-407-error). But the error is pretty clear -- the proxy is expecting authentication that has not been properly provided.

Comment: Right, either the error message is lying or your proxy is not getting the authentication it wants.

Comment: What could be reason for that? @joshp

Comment: It mostly depends on your environment, what does your proxy server require? does Jenkins have the right proxy configuration? If this is not solvable (e.g. System admin won't or can't help), Jenkins command line will let you install a plug-in from local files, if you can download the plug-in via browser or otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## TL;DR

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=THE_PROXY_HOST_NAME -Dhttp.proxyPort=PORT_NUMBER -Dhttp.proxyUser=USER_NAME -Dhttp.proxyPassword=MY_SUPER_SECRET_PASSWORD -Dhttp.auth.preference=basic -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes= -jar jenkins.war
```

Hopefully you've figured it out by now, but for those looking for an answer (myself in the near future)...

I did a lot of things and I'm not sure what really ended up working, but here's what I think worked for me and what I actually did.

## What I think works

Jenkins has known bugs with proxy settings from [JENKINS-58567](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-58567), [JENKINS-56498](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-56498), [JENKINS-48775](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-48775), etc. So here's what I think works:

### Set Java proxy settings

Depending on how you're running Jenkins (i.e. running `java -jar jenkins.war` or as a daemon `systemctl start jenkins.service`) you're going to have to supply the proxy configuration as a Java option.

I'm running this as a daemon so I added my options in **/etc/sysconfig/jenkins** (I have no idea where this lives in Windows) under **JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS** and added the following java options:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=THE_PROXY_HOST_NAME -Dhttp.proxyPort=PORT_NUMBER -Dhttp.proxyUser=USER_NAME -Dhttp.proxyPassword=MY_SUPER_SECRET_PASSWORD -Dhttp.auth.preference=basic -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=
```

I'm guessing that I can probably do  `-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=Basic` instead of `Dhttp.auth.preference=basic -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=` based on this posted [comment](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-48775?focusedCommentId=352126&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-352126), but I'm lazy and don't feel like testing this out (I'll come back to refine this answer someday).

## What I actually did

Apart from the aforementioned steps, I did some weird things (I was pretty desperate, I had gone 4 months without updating plugins).

- Added an export command to my startup script in **/etc/rc.d/init.d/jenkins**

  - `export HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@your-proxy-server:port`
- Added a global variable on Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Global Properties > Checkbox Environment Variable > Add a variable name `HTTP_PROXY` and value `http://username:password@your-proxy-server:port`

I can't remember what else I ended up doing, but I don't think they're important (since they didn't work).

Best of luck!